# Create a base64 md5 hash in bash openssl equivalent to this in node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, openssl

I am currently struggling to generate an expected hash in bash using openssl.

In node.js and c# I have code that generates an output hash with the value of: `kzStnMJObO9gC8gtliznGcTPUeIeIs+OGrwKnUnB34I=`.

The value being hashed is: `IAmAValueToHash`.

The HMAC key being used for hashing is: `M2VlMzRiOTFiNmM0NDY2YWI0MTAxZmZi`.

I am trying to write some bash code that will generate the same output hash using openssl.

Sample node.js code:

```
const { createHmac } = require('crypto');

const valueToHash = 'IAmAValueToHash';

// base 64 encoded format key
const key = 'M2VlMzRiOTFiNmM0NDY2YWI0MTAxZmZi';

const hash = createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(key, 'base64'))
    .update(valueToHash)
    .digest('base64');

console.log(hash);
```

In bash I currently have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

valueToHash="IAmAValueToHash"
key="M2VlMzRiOTFiNmM0NDY2YWI0MTAxZmZi"

printf "%s" "$valueToHash" >> temp.txt

decodedKey=$(echo -n ${key} | base64 --decode)
echo ${decodedKey}

signature=$(openssl md5 -sha256 -hmac ${decodedKey} temp.txt | openssl enc -base64)
printf "%s" "$signature" >> temp2.txt

echo ${signature}
hash=$(sed -n '2p' temp2.txt)
echo ${hash}

rm temp*.txt
```

The value currently being generated by the bash script is:
 `N2Y3NmI2NDAwNDVmOTdiNTAyODE2N2U5Y2U1ZjYwYzkyNzZkZmVjCg==`.

Where as I need it to be:
`kzStnMJObO9gC8gtliznGcTPUeIeIs+OGrwKnUnB34I=`.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of playing about with the options in openssl and various input output formats the following bash implementation created the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash

valueToHash="IAmAValueToHash"
key="M2VlMzRiOTFiNmM0NDY2YWI0MTAxZmZi"

rm -f tmp_*

printf "%s" "$valueToHash" >> tmp_valueToHash
printf "%s" "$key" >> tmp_key

decodedKey=$(base64 --decode -i tmp_key)
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac ${decodedKey} tmp_valueToHash >> tmp_hashed
base64Hash=$(base64 -i tmp_hashed)
echo ${base64Hash}

rm tmp_*
```